# The overwrite method using \r is not working in python 3 [PyCharm]

Tags: python, printing, overwrite

The method to overwrite a line is not working anymore before, back it python 2 it was printing over a line:

For example instead of having:

1%
2%
3%
4%

The line would just update:

1% would become 2% on the same line

I have tried multiple \r methods without success: (I am running pycharm on linux)

```
print('\r', " we've done " + str(trying) + " try so far ")
print( " we've done " + str(trying) + " try so far ","\r")
print( " we've done " + str(trying) + " try so far ",end="\r")
```

I then tried the last solution with a time sleep as someone suggested it was the right one:

```
import time

y = 0
for i in range(100):
    y += 12
    print("we've done " + str(y) + " try so far", end="\r")
    time.sleep(3)
```

But the result is that nothing is printing out. Not a single line.

Comment: what do you mean without success? Show some examples AND give reproducible code. The last option you showed is the one to work with. You need to make sure all your prints are of the same length or padd with spaces to avoid junk staying on the screen

Comment: Are you running in an IDE (like PyCharm)? Can you tell us more about the scenario? The last one has worked just fine for me

Comment: yes i am running on pycharm and the code above was in a while loop where the var trying was increasing @tituszban

Comment: we've done 924 try so far
we've done 934 try so far
we've done 944 try so far
we've done 954 try so far
we've done 964 try so far
we've done 974 try so far
we've done 984 try so far
we've done 994 try so far
we've done 1003 try so far
we've done 1011 try so far
we've done 1021 try so far
we've done 1030 try so far   @Tomerikoo here is an example

Comment: Well, as tituszban said, how are you running this? For example I made a simple code using `'\r'` which ran OK using windows' cmd, but on Python shell didn't

Comment: @Tomerikoo i wrote it just look two comments up =)

Comment: @PablitoGnp PyCharm does not support `\r`. Try running it in a console, and you should see the last one working!

Comment: @PablitoGnp try adding to the `print` arguments `flush=True`

Comment: @Tomerikoo it is working like a regular print. I don't know if pycharm will allow us to clear a print

Comment: Hi @PablitoGnp I just copied your code to Pycharm (on Linux) and got the same result, no printing at all! but when running through the terminal got exactly the output you request. This must be an issue with Pycharm

Answer (score 2):

This is a PyCharm specific issue. It doesn't interpret `\r` as a carriage return. It's raised on [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-66610) issue. If you try and run it in console, you'll see that the last one

```py
print( " we've done " + str(trying) + " try so far ",end="\r")
```

will work.

Comment: it does not print anything at all this is weird  edit: it print partially or nothing or fully it is strange @tituszban

Comment: Can you please describe it more precisely?

Comment: Sometimes i get half of the phrase sometimes nothing sometimes the full phrase throughout the iteration @tituszban

Comment: What's the frequency of the printing?

Comment: @PablitoGnp This makes sense if you're printing on a fast processing loop, so the prints get mixed up. Try adding for example a `time.sleep()` between them and you will see how it works

Comment: @Tomerikoo still not printing  anything

Comment: @PablitoGnp but before you said half prints now you say nothing at all? it's a little hard to support on remote like this, try to be most specific as possible

Comment: @PablitoGnp Update your question, clearly marking (with <hr> horizontal lines and EDIT marks) the new work that has been done, and adding the exact results that you got. Include where and how you ran it, so we can reproduce it.

Comment: @tituszban done i showed what i tried and the results

Comment: It's a good start. Now please add the details on environment. What OS? Windows? Linux? Mac? Where are you running it? CMD? Powershell? PyCharm? IDLE? and so on.

Comment: It should be noted that, at least for me, this issue also occurs in the IDLE shell, which is what brought me to this question. After testing in a normal terminal using `end = "\r"`, it  does, in fact, work.

Answer (score 0):

After several test of multiple solution i still haven't found the solution for clearing a line in Pycharm ide. Can we conclude tha we can't or is there a python solution using a librairy ?

I sometimes uses https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm which somehow is ables to overwrite lines in pycharm but i can't figure out how.

Answer (score -1):

The end should be empty. default is "\n"

```
print(" \r we've done " + str(trying) + " try so far " , end="")
print(" \r we've done " + str(trying) + " try so far ",end="")
print(" \r we've done " + str(trying) + " try so far ",end="")
```

Comment: He needs to print the completion in the same line. I have given the code, which would do the same. print command changed to print function later. What else is the question? I could not understand sorry! Why there is a downvote?

Comment: Not much point in putting the `'\r'` in the start. Basically this prints a space, then goes back and prints the line. Instead changing the default `end` to `'\r'` will make more sense

Comment: @Kris if you take a look at for example progress bar such as the tqdm one it is only taking one print.I want my phrase to be on one line and the number "trying" evolving for example my line could be : ">>> you made 363 tries" and then this same line would turn into  ">>> you made 364 tries"